# Can't read wstrings containing → and print inputted unicode characters

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, wstring, widechar

I'm writing a program which has to work with the characters `↓`, `→` and `¬`. I'm having trouble with reading and printing the characters. This works just fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);

    wstring func = L"x→y";
    wcout << func;
}
```

While this doesn't:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);

    wstring func;
    wcin >> func;
    wcout << func;
}
```

There are different problems for different inputs. For example, for the input `x↓y` the output is `x[?]y`, and if the string contains `→`, then I still have to input something after pressing enter for some reason, and then everything after `→` in the first line is discarded. So for the input

```
x→y
stuff
```

the output is `x[?]stuff`. It would be nice to understand why the weird thing with `→` happens and/or get some solution on maintaining the input and output. I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: The encoding of the source file may be affecting the running program's output.  What is the encoding you are using in your source file?

Comment: The encoding is UTF-8

Comment: You need `_setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_U16TEXT)` to read wide-character input from the console.

Comment: @ErykSun that fixed the problem with → as well. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MariaAyanyan note that if you are on windows, you are using UTF-16 in that case

Answer (score 0):

What about encoding of stdin?
In some cases you can't enter special symbols.